# WinApi - controls are not displayed correctly after resizing the main window

Tags: c++, winapi

**Goal**

I am creating a simple chat client GUI with WinApi.
I'm trying to make the layout responsive so the controls change size / position when the main window is resized and here comes the issue.

**Problem**

Sometimes when the main window is resized, the controls on the right bottom section are not displayed correctly. The new position is fine but they are not painted whole. If I left-click on them, they are displayed correctly again.

This doesn't happen on every resize event, but usually after few attempts.

You can see in the screenshots below:

Default size: https://ibb.co/BNMTM37

Resized: https://ibb.co/6NJqgXp

Resized 2nd ex.: https://ibb.co/dkjVHmt

**Code**

Creating the controls

```
//Rigt bottom box - User nickname area
nicknameArea = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"static", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
    WinDimensions::textOutputWidth + 2 * WinDimensions::margin, WinDimensions::textOutputHeight + 2 * WinDimensions::margin, 150, WinDimensions::editCtrlHeight,
    m_hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_NICKNAME_AREA, 0, 0);

currentNickname = CreateWindowA("static", "Your nickname:", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,              // "Your nickname" label
    WinDimensions::margin, WinDimensions::margin * 1, 120, 20,
    m_hwnd, (HMENU)0, 0, 0);

nicknameEditControl = CreateWindowA("edit", "", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP, // Edit ctrl to change nick
    WinDimensions::margin, WinDimensions::margin * 3, 100, 20,
    m_hwnd, (HMENU)0, 0, 0);

changeNicknameButton = CreateWindowA("button", "Change name", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,            // Button "Change nickname"
    WinDimensions::textOutputWidth + 2 * WinDimensions::margin, WinDimensions::textOutputHeight + 6 * WinDimensions::margin, 100, 25,
    m_hwnd, (HMENU)BUTTON_CHANGENICKNAME, 0, 0);
```

*Note: I've already tried creating the controls with CreateWindowEx (a suggestion I found in a different topic). Also nicknameArea was previously created with CreateWindowA but the behavior remains the same.*

Function called on **WM_SIZE** message:

```
RECT winRect;
if (GetWindowRect(m_hwnd, &winRect)) {
    //Calculating new positions / dimensions
    int newWidth = winRect.right - winRect.left;
    int newHeight = winRect.bottom - winRect.top;

    int rightBoxNewX = newWidth - WinDimensions::rightBarSize + (2 * WinDimensions::margin);
    int bottomBoxesNewY = newHeight - WinDimensions::editCtrlHeight - WinDimensions::buttonYSpace + (2 * WinDimensions::margin);

    //Resizing the text output window
    SetWindowPos(textOutput, NULL, NULL, NULL,
        newWidth - WinDimensions::rightBarSize, newHeight - WinDimensions::editCtrlHeight - WinDimensions::buttonYSpace,
        SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

    //Resizing message input's width and repositioning in Y axes
    SetWindowPos(editControl, NULL, WinDimensions::margin, bottomBoxesNewY,
        newWidth - WinDimensions::rightBarSize, WinDimensions::editCtrlHeight,
        SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

    //Repositioning the send button
    SetWindowPos(sendButton, NULL, WinDimensions::margin, newHeight - WinDimensions::buttonYSpace + (3 * WinDimensions::margin), 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOSIZE);

    //Repositioning the right side column boxes
    SetWindowPos(onlineUsers, NULL,
        rightBoxNewX, WinDimensions::margin, WinDimensions::rightBarSize - (5 * WinDimensions::margin), bottomBoxesNewY - (2 * WinDimensions::margin), SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

    //THESE controls are not working correctly after resizing
    SetWindowPos(nicknameArea, NULL,
       rightBoxNewX, bottomBoxesNewY, NULL, NULL, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOSIZE);

    MoveWindow(changeNicknameButton,
       rightBoxNewX + WinDimensions::margin, bottomBoxesNewY + 7 * WinDimensions::margin,
       100, 25, 0);

    MoveWindow(nicknameEditControl,
        rightBoxNewX + WinDimensions::margin, bottomBoxesNewY + 4 * WinDimensions::margin,
        100, 20, 0);

    MoveWindow(currentNickname,
        rightBoxNewX + WinDimensions::margin, bottomBoxesNewY + WinDimensions::margin,
        120, 20, 0);
}
```

*Note: I used MoveWindow instead of SetWindowPos for the three controls above, because SetWindowPos created much worse-looking results regardless of the flags I put in there*

**WM_PAINT:**

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(m_hwnd, &ps);
    FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));
    EndPaint(m_hwnd, &ps);
}
```

*Note: This is just to fill the background of the main window with white.*

---

I've also tried to make those three faulty controls set to the same HWND parrent, in this case the static control (HWND nicknameArea). The resizing then works fine, but I lose the functionality of my button. And since my knowledge of WinApi isn't very extensive, I can't get my head around subclassing and it always fails somewhere for me (I've seen many tutorials but I always fail to implement it in my existing program).

I'd appreciate any comments or suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `DeferSetWindowPos` rather than `SetWindowPos`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks a lot, this seems to work flawlessly!